# yet another javascript wonder 6 == 6 is false

Tags: javascript

I have this basic code

```
for(var i = 0; i < vm.tickets.length; i++) {   
            console.log(vm.tickets[i].docid);
            console.log(vm.csvData.DOCID);
            console.log(vm.tickets[i].docid == vm.csvData.DOCID);
            if(vm.tickets[i].docid == vm.csvData.DOCID) {
```

I already put `==` and `===` and `=================...`

Logs

> 6
>
> 6
>
> false

Can someone please explain me what is wrong?

Comment: Just guessing, but one of the two has trailing spaces. Verify this with `console.log(vm.tickets[i].docid + "****");`

Comment: lol you are right. I was having a small stroke. How do I remove the spaces?

Comment: with the `trim()` method

Comment: Or you could cast the `docid` as number with `parseInt()`.

Answer (score 0):

As you verified in the comments, one of the two strings has trailing spaces. I'm guessing `vm.csvData.DOCID`. You can remove them with `trim()`, like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < vm.tickets.length; i++) {   
    console.log(vm.tickets[i].docid);
    var csvDocId = vm.csvData.DOCID.trim(); // trim here
    console.log(csvDocId);
    console.log(vm.tickets[i].docid == csvDocId);
    if(vm.tickets[i].docid == csvDocId) {
        // whatever
    }
}
```

Of course you should also trim `vm.tickets[i].docid` if it has trailing spaces as well.